# Square wave generation with STM32 and timer

Tags: timer, signals, stm32

I'm trying to generate a square wave / quadrature signal ( 2 square wave with 90 degres offset). The board is a STM32F103C8
I'm not focused on the frequency yet, I just want to have a clean quadrature signal.
My code is not complicated at the moment and here are the 2 mains fonctions in order to initialize the timer:

```c
void init_SW()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    // Step 1: Initialize GPIO as input for rotary encoder
    // PB7 (TIM4_CH2) (encoder pin A), PB6 (TIM4_CH1) (encoder pin B)
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    // Step 2: Setup TIM4 for encoder input

        RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
        TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
        TIM_TimeBaseStructInit (&TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 3;
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
        TIM_TimeBaseInit (TIM4, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
/*  
  TIM4->CCR3=0 ;
        TIM4->CCR4=(TIM4->ARR+1)/2;
        TIM4->CCER;
        */
}
```

and:

```c
void timer_ccr_init (void)
{
  TIM_OCInitTypeDef  TIM_OCInitStructure;
  /* always initialise local variables before use */
  TIM_OCStructInit (&TIM_OCInitStructure);

  /* Common settings for all channels */
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_Toggle;
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;

  /* Channel1 */
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;
  TIM_OC1Init (TIM4, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

  /* Channel2 - 90 degres after*/
  TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 1;
  TIM_OC2Init (TIM4, &TIM_OCInitStructure);
    TIM4->CCER;
}
```

Do you have any idea where I messed up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite familiar with the F1 line or the Standard Peripheral Library, but I think this is wrong

```
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
```

To connect the timer output signals to the actual pins, you'd rather set them to Alternate Function mode.

This line is at the wrong place:

```
TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
```

Enable the timer at the end, when all channels are set up. Because you are not using the prescaler, and the period is quite short, one channel might do a few cycles while you'd be still setting up the other. However, this would be no problem, if you'd enable the channels simultaneously (this is possible at the register level, but STL might not be able to do it), but

```
TIM4->CCER;
```

on a line alone has no effect (reads the register and discards the value). You should actually set some bits in this register to enable some channels.

```
/* Channel2 - 90 degres after*/
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 1;
```

Because the period is 4 cycles (0 to 3), it would result in a 45 degrees offset. Channel 1 toggled in cycle 0, channel 2 in cycle 1, nothing happens in cycles 2 and 3.

Comment: I made the following changes but my signal still remain disgusting.
I tried both GPIO_Mode_AF_OD and GPIO_Mode_AF_PP but no change
https://pastebin.com/Y64tqzQM
I don't know why my signal is such a mess right now.

Comment: GPIO speed (output drive strength) is set to `GPIO_Speed_2MHz`. With the parameters in your program, the output frequency is F<sub>APB1</sub>/4/2. If it's greater that 2MHz, then the signal will be distorted. You still didn't dive your APB1 frequency, but if it's something like 36 MHz, the maximal value, you'll get 4.5MHz

Comment: Use `GPIO_Speed_10MHz` or `GPIO_Speed_50MHz` for a sharp signal, if you require such a high frequency output.

Comment: OK.
Both APB1 i set to 36Mhz and APB2 is set to 72.
Here my last code: https://pastebin.com/REFzj0EA
and here what my oscillo gave me: http://hpics.li/2a5cee9

Comment: This different but not really square. Same for AF_PP or AF_OD, tried all possibilities with 10Mhz and 50Mhz
http://hpics.li/d553554

Comment: Do you really need a 4.5MHz signal?

Comment: I can lower it but the fasest is the better as I'm convertir a signal resolution to another resolution. What should I change to go a little bit slower?

Comment: What instrument are you using to probe the signal and how is it connected up? Do you have a reference signal source that proves you can successfully probe and display a 4.5MHz signal?